# How to split a window with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I need to write a small application where we can click and drag an image from an "HUD" part of a window (20% of the window) to a "background" part (80%). 
The two part have different background color, and the image does not behave the same way (movement, rotation, scaling with mouse in the background, automatic resize in the HUD).

I am completly new to OpenGL, and I need to finish this by the end of the week, with 2-3 hours of work per day, so I don't think I have the time to explore all it's possibilities.

Could someone give me a pointer to the way I can make this split screen? I think I can manage the rest on my own.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't even have a concept of the window. It only knows about a _framebuffer_. (This framebuffer might be the one "connected" to a window). If you want to restrict drawing into rectangular sub-regions of the framebuffer, you should have a look at [`glViewport()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glViewport.xhtml) and [`glScissor()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glScissor.xhtml).

Comment: Alrigth, I'll try to work with that.